# loading XML files in to a Data extension and using it as a look up table

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Does anyone know if ExactTarget can load a XML file in to a `Data Extension` and how do i do it?

Do i need to convert the XML in to a CSV file?

I want to use the XML as a lookup for an email.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can have XML in a Data Extension column and then parse it with the [BuildRowSetFromXML()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromXML) function or transform it using the [TransformXML()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TransformXML) function and an `XSLT` file in the Portfolio.

I have a sample solution utilizing the `BuildRowSetFromXML()` [here on my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/) .  Here's a snip:

```
%%[

set @node = BuildRowsetFromXML(@productXML,concat("/products/product[",@productPos,"]/productImageURL"),1)
set @productImageURL = Field(Row(@node, 1),'Value')

]%%
```

I'd recommend building the file in Excel, saving it as Unicode (which is tab-delimited) and then importing it with the toolbar import button in SFMC.  You could also write the XML to a DE column using the API.

[image: XML in Excel example]

Answer (score 0):

XML can be stored in a Data Extension.  The field of the Data Extension will need to be a Text type field of an appropriate length to hold the XML you wish to pass.

The XML data can be added to a Data Extension the same way other data would be since it would just be the same as a long string.  This would include an import from a plain text file such as a CSV but other formats are also supported.  Alternatively, it could be added via an API call.

More details:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/data_extensions/